# How can I convert character references to UTF-8 strings in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, utf-8, character

I have some content from feeds. In these feeds, UTF-8 characters are often encoded as character references, ie "å" is "&#xE5;". To avoid double encoding these in my views (ie "&amp;#xE5;") I want to convert these back to normal UTF_8 characters. How can I do this in Ruby?

I want:

"&#xE5;".convert_to_utf8 => "å"

Comment: Perhaps send it through an XML library and see if it will decode the text for you?  Those are XML ways of encoding characters in XML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [HTMLEntities](http://htmlentities.rubyforge.org/) gem is designed to do just this.

```
require 'htmlentities'
coder = HTMLEntities.new
string = "&eacute;lan"
coder.decode(string) # => "élan"
# or
string.decode_entities # => "élan"
```